# Determine whether there exists two bais $B,C$ such that $\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Let $V$ be a vector space, dim V = 3. Let $T : V → V$ be a linear
> transformation such that **dim KerT $= 2$**. Prove there exist ordered
> bases B,C such that
> $\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}$

My attempt:

Let $B=(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}), \ C=(u_{1},u_{2},u_{3})$.

$\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=\left(\left[T\left(v_{1}\right)\right]_{C\ }\left[T\left(v_{2}\right)\right]_{C}\ \left[T\left(v_{3}\right)\right]_{C}\right)=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}$, then we can conclude that

$T\left(v_{1}\right)=0\cdot u_{1}+0\cdot u_{2}+0\cdot u_{3}=0$

$T\left(v_{2}\right)=0\cdot u_{1}+0\cdot u_{2}+0\cdot u_{3}=0$

$T\left(v_{3}\right)=0\cdot u_{1}+0\cdot u_{2}+1\cdot u_{3}=u_{3}$

As **dimKerT$=2$**, $T\left(v_{1}\right)=T\left(v_{2}\right)=0$ and $v_{1},v_{2}$ are linearly independant, $\left\{v_{1},v_{2}\right\}$ is a basis for **KerT**.

Let $v_{3}$ be the vector that completes $\left\{v_{1},v_{2}\right\}$ to a basis of $V$.

Let $u_{3}=T(v_{3})$, and let $u_{1},u_{2}$ be the vectors that complete $\left\{T\left(v_{3}\right)\right\}$ to a basis of $V$.

Then for $B=(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}), \ C=(u_{1},u_{2},T(v_{3}))$, we get $\left[T\right]_{B}^{C}=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}$ ∎

I was wondering if my selection of the basis and reasoning behind what is each vector is correct.. Also, I would be really grateful if anyone can solve it in a different way

Answer (score 1):

I would prove it this way too, but I think it needs to be presented in a more logical order. You shouldn't just let $B$ and $C$ be arbitrary bases, and then apply restrictions to them as you need them, as it's possible that you might accidentally exclude all possible cases. You should build your bases based on these restrictions, from the ground up.

Start by supposing that $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{ker} T$. Such a basis exists because the space has dimension $2$. You know from theorems that $\{v_1, v_2\}$, being a linearly independent set in $V$, can be extended to a basis of $V$. Since $V$ has dimension $3$, we must add only a third vector $v_3$ to form a basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$.

The next step in your construction is to consider $T(v_3)$ and extend it to another basis of $V$. This is only possible if $\{T(v_3)\}$ is linearly independent, which is true if and only if $T(v_3) \neq 0$. There's a very simple reason why $T(v_3) \neq 0$, but it should be included in your proof.

You let $u_3 = T(v_3)$, then extend it to a basis $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$. Then it's a matter of showing that the matrix form is what we expect it to be. Your logic previously showed that, if the matrix is to have that form, then our bases would have to satisfy the previous conditions, but the converse is what we're interested in! We want to know that, now that we have constructed our basis, the matrix will indeed have the given form.

Consider $Tv_1$ and $Tv_2$. We assumed already that $v_1, v_2 \in \operatorname{ker} T$. This means that
\begin{align*}
T(v_1) &= 0 = 0u_1 + 0u_2 + 0u_3 \\
T(v_2) &= 0 = 0u_1 + 0u_2 + 0u_3.
\end{align*}
What about $Tv_3$? By definition of $u_3$, it is exactly equal to $Tv_3$, thus
$$Tv_3 = u_3 = 0u_1 + 0u_2 + 1u_3.$$
Thus, by definition, $[T]_B^C$ is the matrix you need it to be.